# Linq to XML with n number of dynamic where conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

hi i want to use **n number of dynamic where** conditions for my solutions..

and in my scenario i've to fetch all the xml elements which all *must contains all the elements of the array* ( arrSearchContents ) which is build by splitting all the words of the strSearchContent.

```
<Mobiles>
  <Mobile Id="1">
    <MDetails ModelNo="1" Desc="x phone color red"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="2" Desc="x phone color green"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="3" Desc="x phone color blue"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="4" Desc="x phone color black"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="5" Desc="x phone color yellow"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="6" Desc="x phone color pink"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="7" Desc="x phone color gray"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="8" Desc="x phone color silver"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="9" Desc="x phone color orange"/>
  </Mobile>
  <Mobile Id="2">
    <MDetails ModelNo="11" Desc="y phone color red"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="12" Desc="y phone color green"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="13" Desc="y phone color blue"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="14" Desc="y phone color black"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="15" Desc="y phone color yellow"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="16" Desc="y phone color pink"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="17" Desc="y phone color gray"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="18" Desc="y phone color silver"/>
    <MDetails ModelNo="19" Desc="y phone color orange"/>
  </Mobile>
  <Mobile Id="3">
  ......
  <Mobile>
  ......
</Mobiles>
```

i want a solution something like bellow code.
can any body ***rectify*** the code

```
public void doSearch(string strSearchContent)
{
string[] arrSearchContents;
arrSearchContents = strSearchContent.Split(' ');

string fileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\XMLFiles/Mobile.xml");
XDocument doc = null;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

        IEnumerable<XElement> list1 =
            from elements in doc.Descendants("MDetails")
            where
                for(int i=0;i<arrSearchContents.Length;i++)
                {
                    elements.Attribute("Desc").Value.Contains(arrSearchContents[i]) &&
                }
            select elements;
    }
}
```

the selected list should contains all the key words of search string.

```
as per example : if strSearchContent = "phone color blue"

then as a result it should return :

<MDetails ModelNo="3" Desc="x phone color blue"/>
<MDetails ModelNo="13" Desc="y phone color blue"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from d in doc.Descendants("MDetails")
let desc = (string)d.Attribute("Desc")
where desc != null && 
      arrSearchContents.All(keyword => desc.Contains(keyword))
select d;
```

But it also will match "bluephonecolor". If you want to match words you can use regular expression, or split description by words:

```
!arrSearchContents.Except(desc.Split()).Any()
```

Comment: @pks welcome, btw if all `MDetails` elements have `Desc` attribute you can omit `desc != null` check. Also keep in mind, that `String.Split()` without arguments by default splits string by words. And.. if answer worked for you, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

You should check it **node attribute** contains value, not vise-verse

```
var str = @"<Mobiles>
                    <Mobile Id=""1"">
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""1"" Desc=""x phone color red""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""2"" Desc=""x phone color green""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""3"" Desc=""x phone color blue""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""4"" Desc=""x phone color black""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""5"" Desc=""x phone color yellow""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""6"" Desc=""x phone color pink""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""7"" Desc=""x phone color gray""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""8"" Desc=""x phone color silver""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""9"" Desc=""x phone color orange""/>
                    </Mobile>
                    <Mobile Id=""2"">
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""11"" Desc=""y phone color red""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""12"" Desc=""y phone color green""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""13"" Desc=""y phone color blue""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""14"" Desc=""y phone color black""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""15"" Desc=""y phone color yellow""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""16"" Desc=""y phone color pink""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""17"" Desc=""y phone color gray""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""18"" Desc=""y phone color silver""/>
                        <MDetails ModelNo=""19"" Desc=""y phone color orange""/>
                    </Mobile></Mobiles>";

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
    var strSearchContent = "phone color blue";
    IEnumerable<XElement> list1 = doc.XPathSelectElements("//MDetails")
                                     .Where(node => node.Attribute("Desc").Value.Contains(strSearchContent));

    //LinqPad specific print call
    list1.Dump();
```

Prints

```
<MDetails ModelNo="3" Desc="x phone color blue" /> 
<MDetails ModelNo="13" Desc="y phone color blue" />
```

So resulting code will look like this (Note that I've changed the return type of a method):

```
public IEnumerable<XElement> doSearch(string strSearchContent)
{
    string fileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\XMLFiles/Mobile.xml");

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        return doc.XPathSelectElements("//MDetails")
                  .Where(node => node.Attribute("Desc").Value.Contains(strSearchContent));
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<XElement>();
}
```

Comment: btw, you can actually put the condition into the xpath: "//MDetails[contains(@Desc, {0})]" (where {0} is your search term)

Comment: Yes, sure, but I don't like to create long XPath expressions in LINQ to XML. XPath is not well known by many developers, so I use it only to select `all` elements in the DOM with specified name. Else is done by LINQ in statically typed manner. Again - there can be lots of options here. Thanks for response